# Extraer texto con determinado caracter que se repite

Tags: sql, transact-sql

Buen dia,
tengo un campo sobre una tabla de SQL Server que guarda un texto en HTML ya que así luego lo consulta la aplicación. Estoy construyendo un reporte pero aquí debo extraer solo el texto limpio sin etiquetas HTML, el escenario es algo así como este.

`<div><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;">Parque Rionegro&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;">Se requiere realizar soldadura a tubos ingreso puerta</span></div>`

De este bloque necesito extraer este texto.

"Se requiere realizar soldadura a tubos ingreso puerta"

otro ejemplo
`<div><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;">Parque Guatapé&nbsp; &nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif;">Revisar reflector ubicado cerca al kiosco, no están funcionando</span></div>`

Necesitaría extraer este bloque de texto.
"Revisar reflector ubicado cerca al kiosco, no están funcionando"

Gracias por cualquier sugerencia, he intentado con substring pero no me he logrado retornarlo como lo necesito.

Comment: Hacer eso no es tan sencillo, debes intentar hacer algo como un analizador léxico

Comment: Nunca he usado ms-sql, pero supongo que [algo parecido a esto](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=c84893c9946ecd3e1c7c59907795accf) te servirá. Al final, `html` es un tipo de `xml` ¡Muy buena suerte!